# AOSP / Android 7: How is EGL utilized in detail?

Tags: android, android-source, surfaceflinger

I am trying to understand the Android (7) Graphics System from the system integrators point of view. My main focus is the minimum functionality that needs to be provided by libegl.

I understand that surfaceflinger is the main actor in this domain. Surfaceflinger initialized EGL, creates the actual EGL surface and acts as a consumer for buffers (frames) created by the app. The app again is executing the main part of required GLES calls. Obviously, this leads to restrictions as surfaceflinger and apps live in separate processes which is not the typical use case for GLES/EGL.

Things I do not understand:

- Do apps on Android 7 always render into EGL_KHR_image buffers which are send to surfaceflinger? This would mean there's always an extra copy step (even when no composition is needed), as far as I understand... Or is there also some kind of optimized fullscreen mode, where apps do directly render into the final EGL surface?
- Which inter-process sharing mechanisms are used here? My guess is that EGL_KHR_image, used with EGL_NATIVE_BUFFER_ANDROID, defines the exact binary format, so that an image object may be created in each process, where the memory is shared via ashmem. Is this already the complete/correct picture or do I miss something here?

I'd guess these are the main points I am lacking confident knowledge about, at the moment. For sure, I have some follow-up questions about this (like, how do gralloc/composition fit into this?), but, in accordance to this platform, I'd like to keep this question as compact as possible. Still, besides the [main documentation page](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics), I am missing documentation clearly targeted at system integrators. So further links would be really appreciated.

My current focus are typical use cases which would cover the vast majority of apps compatible with Android 7. If there are corner cases like long deprecated compatibility shims, I'd like to ignore them for now.